# Restore or re-enable the VLC GUI

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player

I was mucking around with VLC setting up an HTTP interface and somehow I've managed to turn off the default GUI - which I believe is the Qt interface. Now when I start VLC I get the process showing up in TaskManager (I'm on Windows 7) but no GUI.

How can I re-enable GUI without an uninstall|install?

I don't want to do this because I want to keep mucking around with it and if I accidentally turn off the GUI again I don't want to have to go through some uninstall|reinstall loop.

I thought it would just be a config file entry somewhere but can't find the file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to reset VLC Media Player's preferences and cache from its menu in Start->All Programs.

You can also do it manually from command prompt (cmd):

- In command prompt browse to the VLC's installation directory.
- Type `vlc.exe --reset-config` to reset preferences and `vlc.exe
  --reset-plugins-cache` to reset cache.
- You can also type all together as `vlc.exe --reset-config
  --reset-plugins-cache`.

Comment: Sure did. Thx a bunch. I had deleted the folder from my start menu and just had the link to the .exe. For once all the other junk served some purpose. :)

Comment: Thats cool.. @rism. Thats all came from your own answer that you submitted first. I checked in my `Start` and found `"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -Iskins` as the shortcut to open vlc with other skin. Then checked "Reset" options' shortcut and it is `"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache vlc://quit`. Thats how it worked. Thanks to you too, Dear. :)

Answer (score 0):

A work around answer is to provide a switch to the executable. i.e.

This runs an interface:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -Iskins

This just runs a service:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"

But I've still no idea where the appropriate config file is.
Using the above method i can get back in and set the interface back to default.. but that doesn't alter the switch on the shortcut so it must have a config file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be necessary to manually delete or reset config files.

To deactivate minimal interface on windows, you can press ctrl+h.