# VLC, Windows 10, video playback is mirrored

Tags: vlc-media-player

In a single instance window of VLC, the MP4 file is output as two side-by-side videos simultaneously.
This does not happen with all MP4 files.
Is there a setting to solve this or is it a source file issue? I've seen it with other MP4 files before.

Comment: “Are you perhaps trying to play a video that’s intended to be seen through 3D glasses? Two simultaneous identical videos sounds like that’s the case.

Comment: Have you cleared/reset your VLC settings on this client? https://superuser.com/questions/386844/restore-or-re-enable-the-vlc-gui